# Lua Text and function print in the same line

Tags: lua

Can any body help me ?

```
function sum(_g, _h)
    local num = (_g * _h) / 2
    return num
end

print("The result is")(sum(10, 6))
```

Why this isn't working ?

Comment: `sum10, 6` or `sum(10, 6)` ?

Comment: sum(10, 6) is correct

Comment: You should post the error you are getting. (Since you are clearly getting one.) Then you should try to actually read the code you wrote the way `lua` sees it. Hint: `print("The result is")` is a complete function call. What does it return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `print` takes one or more strings as arguments.
When the strings are entered as different arguments, it outputs them separated by a tab

```
The result is    20
```

To get this output, just imagine you store the return from `sum` in a variable

```
res = sum(10, 6)
```

And then call `print` entering your string and the result just like you enter `10` and `6` in your function `sum`:

```
print("The result is ", res)
```

This also traduces to

```
print("The result is ", sum(10, 6))
```

Without needing to store the result anywhere.

Anyway if you target an output which looks like

```
The result is 20
```

you must enter only one string as the argument for `print`

```
..
```

is the operator which lets you concatenate two string in one string, so that `"hello".." world"` results in `"hello world"`.

Now just combine the two strings `"The result is "` and `20` (which actually is a number, but it gets automatically converted to a string) with the `..` operator, as in

```
res = sum(10, 6)
mystring = "The result is "
print(mystring..res)
```

Or, more shortly

```
print("The result is "..sum(10, 6))
```

Comment: No problem! Just ask if you need more help.